# Computing HOG feature on a single point using Matlab "extractHOGFeature" function

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I'm confused with matlab "extractHOGFeature" function. I have an depth image (370x89). I want to calculate HOG on single point in an image. When I give the point[i,j] sometime it returns empty vector(0x36) and when I swap the points[i,j] to [j,i] the function return a non empty vector(1x36). Additionally I ran the function in the loop for every pixel[i,j],[j,i] and whole image separately and count the non-empty HOG vector and surprisingly I got different numbers. Let me explain in the example below.

with coordinates [i,j].

```
   count=0; 
    mx=imread('abc_gray.png');
    for i=1:size(mx,1)
        for j=1:size(mx,2)
            XY=[i,j];
            hog=extractHOGFeatures(double(mx),XY);
            if ~ isempty(hog)
               count=count+1;
            end 
        end
    end

**Total number of non-empty vector: 5994**
```

with coordinates [j,i]

```
count=0; 
      mx=imread('abc_gray.png');
      for i=1:size(mx,1)
          for j=1:size(mx,2)
              XY=[j,i];
              hog=extractHOGFeatures(double(mx),XY);
              if ~ isempty(hog)
                  count=count+1;
              end 
          end
      end

**Total number of non-empty vector: 26270**
```

which one is the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `extractHOGFeatures` function accepts `x,y` coordinates or **column, row** coordinates.  This means that the second version of the `for` loop is the correct one.  You are getting empty vectors sometimes because the coordinates you are specifying are going out of bounds in the image.  This is happening because the rows and columns are flipped so there is a potential to go beyond the dimensions of the rows or columns.  In addition, given your logic you technically should have `370 x 89 = 32930` HOG descriptors - one for each point.  However, you have to remember that we concentrate on a window **surrounding** each point.  If the window goes out of bounds given the point, then the HOG descriptor cannot be computed.  This is why there is less than 32930 HOG descriptors to compute.

Also, running `extractHOGFeatures` on the entire image and comparing this to individual points will definitely give you different sizes.  What's happening is that for the entire image, there is a **block-stride**, meaning that there will be overlap between cells in the image so your dimensionality of the HOG feature vector will be larger than if you were to compute the HOG descriptor of each point separately.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: I will not apply HOG on every pixel in an image. Probably I will retrieve few hundred pixel randomly from an image and apply HOG on it.

Comment: No problem at all.  These are great questions.  Keep asking!

Comment: @FaisalSajjad If you do that, make sure the random order is remembered.  You want to do this so that the way you are computing your HOG features is reproducible.  I would recommend doing something like: `[x,y] = meshgrid(1:size(mx, 2), 1:size(mx, 1)); XY = [x(:) y(:)]; ind = randperm(size(XY, 1)); XY = XY(ind(1:200),:);`.  `XY` will contain 200 random coordinates to sample from in the image **that are all unique**, and you can use `XY` for further analysis later on.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your great help. I will surely consider this suggestion in my implementation.